# Convert OptionalDouble to Optional <java.lang.Double>

Tags: java, java-8, average, option-type

I have a method that builds a list and I want it to return the average of the list as an Optional value.

However, when I calculate the average value using Java 8, I always get the return value as an OptionalDouble.

How do I convert

```
OptionalDouble to Optional<Double>?
```

Below are my code for average calculation:

```
private static Optional<Double> averageListValue() {
     // Build list
     List<Double> testList = new ArrayList<>();
     testList.add(...);
     ...
     ...


     return testList.stream().mapToDouble(value -> value).average();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: How about `getAsDouble` on OptionalDouble which will get you the average in `double` which is what you will finally want.

Comment: An OptionalDouble is more efficient; nearer to `double`, so transforming the using code from `Optional<Double>` to `OptionalDouble` would seem better. But then, I think you know that and have your reason.

Comment: If the code builds a list like shown, you already know that it will never be empty. So why returning an `Optional` at all?

Comment: @VHS Thanks for the suggestion.  Apparently this method is reaching a consensus here as well.

Comment: @JoopEggen Thanks for the info.  Yeah I got my reason...

Comment: @Holger There are some details I am skipping here, but the actual usage might lead an empty List.

Answer (score 12):

I'd go for this approach:

```
private static Optional<Double> convert(OptionalDouble od) {
    return od.isPresent() ? 
        Optional.of(od.getAsDouble()) : Optional.empty();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

A slight variation on [@Andremoniy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42213091/1553851) is to skip the `DoubleStream` and use the `averagingDouble()` collector:

```
if (testList.isEmpty()) {
    return Optional.empty();
}
return Optional.of(testList.stream().collect(Collector.averagingDouble()));
```

Or consider whether 0 is a valid return value for an empty list, and possibly skip the `Optional` entirely.

Answer (score 5):

BTW, I found another solution, which has most simple form.

I've started thinking about: when result of average can be empty? Only when list it self is empty, right? So if we are sure that list is not empty, than we can safely do `getAsDouble()`:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(testList.isEmpty() ? null : 
        testList.stream().mapToDouble(v -> v).average().getAsDouble())
```

(from performance point of view this could be more efficient than creating additional lambda wrappers, as was suggested in similar answers.)

Comment: This is a double-test, first `isEmpty()`, then a `null` test within `ofNullable`. There is no need for the second test: `return testList.isEmpty()? Optional.empty(): Optional.of(testList.stream().mapToDouble(v -> v).average().getAsDouble());`

Comment: I thought about it, but I specifically put ternary operation inside `Optional.ofNullable`. It is more stylish thing, while I agree that it has one more comparison operation

Answer (score 4):

This is quite an old question, but in newer versions of Java you can:

```java
// Given an OptionalDouble
var myOptionalDouble = OptionalDouble.of(3.0d);

// Convert to Optional<Double>
var myOptional = myOptionalDouble.stream().boxed().findFirst();
```

The reverse is similarly easy:

```java
var myOptional = Optional.of(Double.valueOf(3.0d));

var myOptionalDouble = myOptional.stream().mapToDouble(t -> t).findFirst();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there exists a neat solution, but ths should work:

```
OptionalDouble optionalDouble = testList.stream().mapToDouble(value -> value).average();
return Optional.ofNullable(optionalDouble.isPresent() ? optionalDouble.getAsDouble() : null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, I wanted to see if it could be written in a single statement, without any need for an OptionalDouble temp variable. Here is the best I came up with:

```
return testList.stream().collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
    Collectors.summarizingDouble(Double::doubleValue),
    stat -> Optional.ofNullable(stat.getCount()>0 ? stat.getAverage() : null)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I came to this "one line" (single statement) solution:

```
    return ((Function<OptionalDouble, Optional<Double>>) od
            -> od.isPresent() ? Optional.of(od.getAsDouble()) : Optional.empty())
            .apply(testList.stream().mapToDouble(v -> v).average());
```

---

BTW, just for sake of minimalism, if you will do static import:

```
import static java.util.Optional.*;
```

you can omit `Optional.`, what makes it a little bit less messy.