# Why no OptionalDouble orElseNull() or a better solution

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type

I have a stream calculating average costs the code looks something like this

```
private Double calculateAverageCost(List<Item> items) {
    return items.stream()
                .mapToDouble(item -> item.cost)
                .filter(cost -> cost > 0) // Ignore zero cost items
                .average()
                . // Something here to convert an OptionalDouble to value or null
}
```

I need the method to return the value or `null` if there is no value (e.g. when all costs are zero). My problem is there is no `orElseNull` method on `OptionalDouble` to do the conversion. I can do it in another step e.g.

```
private Double calculateAverageCost(List<Item> items) {
    final OptionalDouble average = items.stream()
                .mapToDouble(item -> item.cost)
                .filter(cost -> cost > 0) // Ignore zero cost items
                .average();
    return average.isPresent() ? average.getAsDouble() : null;
}
```

I realise this is a "primitive" stream and my method is returning boxed `Double` but it would seem like this could be helpful, similar to (`Optional.empty().orElseGet(null)`).

Is there a reason or a better solution im missing?

Comment: How about using `map` instead of `mapToDouble`?

Comment: @AndyTurner Only the primitive stream specializations have `average()`. `Stream<Double>` doesn't have it. Do you could do it with a reduce, but it'd be uglier

Comment: Why not simply have the method return an `OptionalDouble`? I mean ... that is exactly why optionals were introduced. They signal the possible absence of a value after calling some method.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`OptionalDouble` contains a **primitive** double. If you want an optional of a wrapped double you can just use `Optional<Double>`. Primitives can't be null, so `orElseNull` does not make sense.

As for how to convert between the two, it already has an answer here: [Convert OptionalDouble to Optional <java.lang.Double>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42210935/convert-optionaldouble-to-optional-java-lang-double). TL;DR there is no nice, native way to do it yet. Wait for [valhalla](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/218).

Answer (score 1):

If you are returning `null` just to indicate that all costs are `0`(or the list is empty), then you could return `Double.NaN` instead. This would allow your return type to be primitive `double`.

```java
private double calculateAverageCost(List<Item> items) {
    return items.stream()
                .mapToDouble(item -> item.cost)
                .filter(cost -> cost > 0) // Ignore zero cost items
                .average()
                .orElse(Double.NaN);
}
```

```java
double avg = calculateAverageCost(items);
if(Double.isNaN(avg)) {
    System.out.println("All costs are zero");
}
```

Otherwise, you could just use `orElse(0d)`. Since you are filtering **only positive costs**, the average would be `0` only if all costs are 0 (or if the list is empty). So if the result is 0, then it definitely implies the absence of positive costs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.boxed()` function of `DoubleStream` in your chain after `mapToDouble()`, that will convert your `DoubleStream` chain *(stream of primitive)* to `Stream<Double>` chain *(stream of wrapper)*.

Your chain will look like:

```
  items.stream()
    .mapToDouble(item -> item.cost)
    .filter(cost -> cost > 0)
    .boxed() 
    .collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(Double::doubleValue)); //can't use average() function of DoubleStream
```